# How to make a html paragraph indent in java?

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I tried this to get a indent on a html page in eclipse but does not seem to work. How can I get the indent?

```
out.println("<p class=\"indent\">" + meaning + "</p>");
```

Comment: Please don't write HTML in Java code.

Comment: Have you styled the `indent` class using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You need CSS for this. The [`text-indent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) will do what you're looking for. Here's an example using inline CSS:

```
 out.println("<p style=\"text-indent: 10px;\">" + meaning + "</p>");
```

Or in your stylesheet, define your `indent` class:

```
.indent {
     text-indent: 10px
}
```